Is it possible to keep an XML reference of an Excel file while editing it with python?
I have an xlsx file from a configuration package of my business central with a given table that I've to feed with a lot of data from a database. After editing the file with openpyxl it always "loses" its XML reference and I'm not able to upload it back to BC. I always have to do the extra step to open the file manually, copy the data and paste it into the original file to keep the XML reference.
Does anyone has a solution how to keep the XML reference or add it after editing the xlsx file?
My code:
    def write_data_to_excel(self, df: pd.DataFrame, file_path: str = None):
        print(self.boolean_columns)
        file_path = self._check_path(file_path)
        wb = xl.load_workbook(file_path)
        ws = wb.active
        new_row_count = 0
        for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
            for column_index in range(len(df.columns)):
                current_row = self.start_row + hash(row_index)
                current_column = self.start_column + column_index
                value = row[df.columns[column_index]]
                try:
                    if current_column in self.boolean_columns:
                        value = settings.TRUE_VALUE if value == 1 else settings.FALSE_VALUE
                    ws.cell(current_row, current_column, value)
                except IllegalCharacterError as e:
                    print(f"IllegalCharactorError1:{e} (row: {current_row}, column: {current_column})")
                    value = self._replace_illegal_characters(value)
                except ValueError:
                    value = settings.FALSE_VALUE if current_column in self.boolean_columns else ""    
                ws.cell(current_row, current_column, value)
                {current_column})")
                new_row_count = self.start_row + hash(row_index)

        for table in ws.tables.values():
            table.ref = f"A3:CY{new_row_count}"
        wb.save(file_path)

The Excel file with it's schema, which is lost after editing it with openpyxl.
XLSX file with correct schema
Tried to download the xlsx, fill it with data and upload it again to business central

What do you mean by "XML reference"?

There's no "XML reference" in Excel or this code. There's only code that stores values unprocessed values in cells, whether they can be used in Excel or not. No effort is made to specify the cell style so even dates can end up appearing as numbers instead of actual dates.

You don't seem to be processing or formatting anything, so why not use pd.to_excel ?

The excel file already has an xml schema. When I download it from business central, I get an xlsx file with xml schema but after filling it with data the schema just desapear and I can't figure out why.
Step by step:

Download xlsx from business central
loading data from database
bring data to panda dataframe
load data from panda dataframe to excel file with openpyxl
try to upload the file to business central
getting the error that no XML reference was found


I just need a schema to upload the excel file to business central again. I might lag some knowledge of how XML schemas / references in excel work, espically when I want to keep/define them with python. But i couldn't find any good references for this topic.

Some things that Openpyxl doesn't work well with, can you use Xlwings instead?

Never heard of Xlwings before. I will check it out or do you already know a solution how to implement a xml file to excel and keep the strucutre as reference?

@Sebastian Heyde You'd need to flag a comment with the persons name if you want them notified of the comment (only 1 name allowed). The author of the Question or Answer commented on will always be notified so me adding your name in this comment is only for example of use but otherwise unnecessary here. Xlwings is VBA using Python, so it uses the Excel App and whatever you can do in Excel with VBA in most cases can be duplicated in Python with Xlwings. However in general, because Xlwings is using the Excel app it will not lose the XML schema when the workbook is saved unlike Openpyxl..

At the end I just used win32com to write the data to my excel file. This haven't removed my XML schema BUT it was horribly slow. It works and keeps the schema but if you need to write a lot of data it's not the right solution. Might keep looking at other languages / framworks.
PS: Didn't got win32coms XMLImport to work. That might have been a solution to write the data with openpyxl and add the XML schema after writing the data.
Anyway...thanks for all your help!
